# How to change dynamically Data Flow in pipeline ADF-AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i have question is possible to change dynamic Data Flow in "foreach", not only parameters. I need run multi Data flows in on loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU0YX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVmpQ.png)

Comment: Currently, it may not be possible in ADF. But you can try using a switch case inside ForEach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, in ADF it is not supported to give the dynamic dataflow names or pipeline names in the activities.

As an alternative, you can try Switch to get the desired result.

First store all the dataflow names in an array like below.

[image]

Give this to ForEach activity.

[image]

Inside ForEach use the Switch activity and give the `@item()` as Expression.

**Switch activity:**

[image]

**Cases:**

[image]

**For case names, give all dataflow names that you want to execute and inside the cases create the respective dataflows.**

**Inside a case(case name is `dataflowA`):**

[image]

You can see the Execution of the dataflow inside ForEach activity.

[image]

Comment: It looks nice :) I have question, how many elements can be added in the switch, i have more than 300 Data flows. in one pipeline i need added adlist ~70, it will work? I asking because ading in - "normall way" dataflows in pieple max is 40.

Comment: As per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-switch-activity#type-properties), the switch cases limit is only 25 cases. As the limit is not sufficient for you, this approach may work for you. But it requires lot of manual work. give 25 or 24 cases and in default case give execute pipeline activity. Inside the child pipeline repeat the same process as parent pipeline till all your dataflows list completes.

Comment: It involves lot of manual work but as it is not supported in ADF, we can try this.